# MapReduce job is stuck on a multi node Hadoop-2.7.1 cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have successfully run Hadoop 2.7.1 on a multi node cluster (1 namenode and 4 datanodes). But, when I run MapReduce job (WordCount example from Hadoop website), it always stuck at this point.

```
[~@~ hadoop-2.7.1]$ bin/hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /user/inputdata/ /user/outputdata
15/09/30 17:54:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/09/30 17:54:57 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/09/30 17:54:58 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/09/30 17:54:59 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/09/30 17:55:00 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/09/30 17:55:00 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1443606819488_0002
15/09/30 17:55:00 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1443606819488_0002
15/09/30 17:55:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://~~~~:8088/proxy/application_1443606819488_0002/
15/09/30 17:55:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1443606819488_0002
```

Do I have to specify a memory for `yarn`?

> NOTE: DataNode hardwares are really old (Each has 1GB RAM).

Appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not easy to see what is the real problem with your job. Please, post the output of yarn logs. Yes, you need to specify memory for yarn. Have you configured it at all?

Comment: @facha I have configured `yarn` and `mapred` `xml`s as it suggested in Hadoop website. Now, i will try to edit with my `.log`.

Answer (score 1):

The data nodes memory (1gb) is really very scarce to prepare atleast 1 container to run mapper/reducer/am in it.

You could try lowering the below container memory allocation values in `yarn-site.xml` with very lower values to get the container created on them.

```
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
```

Also try to reduce the below properties values in your job configration,

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
mapreduce.map.java.opts
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
```

Comment: All I have in my `yarn-site.xml` is default one, which is `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services`. My `mapred-site.xml` only has `mapreduce.framework.name`. And could you please provide how exactly should I set them. Thank you.

Comment: kindly go through this link, will be helpful. http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/

Comment: I have set properties as mentioned, but still out of lack. In addition, now my DataNodes don't start :)